# Passing a SqlConnection to class library file (dll)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, class

I am busy developing a class library project in C# to be reused and attached to different projects in future.  It will mainly be used for Table Valued Parameters.  My question is, how do I pass a SQL connection to it?  The connection will be instantiated in another (main project) that the .dll gets attached to.

I currently have a Class Library Project, and have a Console Application Project created in the same solution for testing purposed.

One last requirement is that I don't want to use ConfigurationManager as the connection string will not be stored in app.config or web.config and by default the queries must be passed back to the calling application.

I've come accross a couple of links like the one below, but nothing I can really use:

[Sharing a connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584368/sharing-a-connection-string)

Please excuse the noobness, I am 7 weeks into professional programming.

Comment: When you use your class library you will at some point instantiate a class, or invoke a method from the main application. At one of these points you can pass the connection string as a string argument.

Comment: Something like this: public void nameOfSub(string dataConnection)
{Code goes here}

Comment: are you trying to share an open connection or just the connection string, and opening the connection in the DLL?

Comment: All very helpful so far, thanks guys.  From what I can see, the connection needs to be instantiated in the calling application.  @Yakyb, I only need to share the connection string.  I will try to post some code shortly of what I have so far.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: My eyes hurt at some of the comments and the answer provided. Why don't you guys just pass a friggin' instance of a connection object instead of the connection string?

Comment: because that is not what has been asked for, and its not entirely clear what is being attempted here.

Comment: @Yakyb it seems to me that it **is** what's being asked here. OP says they want to pass a connection to a library. They say something about sharing strings but it's clear that's not the path they wish to follow.

Comment: agreed, although in the 4th comment they state they only need to share the string

Comment: @Renan A good case for passing the connection instead of the connection string is where you want to use [transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) over several queries and have the opportunity to roll back changes from earlier queries from results of later queries (you would pass the connection object and the transaction object to the function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dll, simply require an `IDbConnection` or `IDbCommand`. All the method is then properly abstracted against the interfaces for the data access.

For example:

In your shared dll

```
public static int LookUpIntForSomething(IDbConnection connection)
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // use command.
    }
}
```

In your calling app

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    var int = DbQueries.LookupIntForSomething(connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is excellent example for dependency injection. I would recommend using enterprise library unity for this kind of stuff. In your data access layer library I would define interface:

```
public interface IConnectionProvider {
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}

public interface IAccountProvider {
   Account GetAccountById(int accountID);
}

internal class AccountProvider : IAccountProvider {
    private IConnectionProvider _connectionProvider;
    public AccountProvider(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
        if (connectionProvider == null) {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionProvider");
        }
        _connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
    }
   public Account GetAccountById(int accountID) {
       Account result;
       using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionProvider)) {
         // retrieve result here
       }
       return result;
   }
}

public static class Bootstrapper {
    public static void Init() {
        ServiceLocator.AddSingleton<IAccountProvider, AccountProvider>();
    }
}
```

Then in any assembly using your data access library you can define implementation for IConnectionProvider, like this:

```
internal class WebConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider {
    public string ConnectionString { get { return "Server=..."; } }
}

internal static class WebBootstrapper {
    public static void Init() {
        Bootstrapper.Init();
        ServiceLocator.AddSingleton<IConnectionProvider, WebConnectionProvider>();
    }
}
```

And anywhere after you call WebBootstrapper.Init() in your assembly you can use:

```
var accountProvider = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IAccountProvider>();
accountProvider.GetAccountById(1);
```

Service locator:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;


public class ServiceLocator {
  private IUnityContainer m_Container = new UnityContainer();

  public void Add<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom {
    m_Container.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>();
  }

  public void BuildUp<T>(T instance) {
    m_Container.BuildUp<T>(instance);
  }

  public void BuildUp(Type type, object instance) {
    m_Container.BuildUp(type, instance);
  }

  public void AddSingleton<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom {
    m_Container.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  }

  public void AddInstance<T>(T instance) {
    m_Container.RegisterInstance<T>(instance);
  }

  public T Resolve<T>() {
    return m_Container.Resolve<T>();
  }

  private static ServiceLocator m_Instance;

  public static ServiceLocator Instance {
    get { return m_Instance; }
  }

  static ServiceLocator() {
    m_Instance = new ServiceLocator();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if i understand your requirements correctly,I'm not sure that i do, i would setup a static struct as such

```
public static struct ConnectionString
{
    public int ID;
    public string Connection;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Connection;
    }

   public static ConnectionString DataBase1 = new ConnectionString{ ID = 1 , Connection = "YourConnectionStringhere"};
   public static ConnectionString DataBase2 = new ConnectionString{ ID = 2 , Connection = "YourConnectionString2here"};

}
```

and then use it as such

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var I = ReferencedDll.DoSomething(ConnectionString.DataBase1.ToString());
 }
```

or

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var ClassFromDll = new ReferencedDll.SomeClass(ConnectionString.DataBase1.ToString());

    ClassFromDll.DoSomething();
 }
```

of course this leaves your connection strings hard coded which is not ideal